# Vim flake8 python 3.6 support

Tags: vim, python-3.6, flake8

I've been looking for a little time now, and can't find an answer to my problem.
I'm coding on vim and I tried the new format string version `f'whatever {a_var}'`, but my flake8 / syntastic keep telling me that's a syntax error.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this ?

I already had a problem with vim-jedi for python3.6 and virtualenv, and after hours of research I found a hack in some github issue, but here I can't find anything.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to verify that your `flake8` script uses `python3.6`. Run `which flake8` in command line, open the file in vim (or directly run `vim $(which flake8)`) and see the shebang line (the first line of the file, it starts with `#!`). If it's not `python3.6` — edit the line.

Comment: That's perfect, I have now only the pylint error (as I have vim syntastic, which runs all the checker). My flake8 test are fine. The pylint error is [syntax-error] invalid syntax (<string>, line 15). I'm gonna try to find how to update that to.

Comment: Found it. I just upgraded the pylint in my virtualenv. Thanks again !

Comment: I was able to make your solution work by pointing the shebang line at my pyenv shim. I'd be curious to know if you or anyone else has tried this and if there are any pitfalls in doing so.

Comment: @pdoherty926 A better way would be to install `flake8` using said `pyenv` shim and its `pip`. Even better — use [virtual environemnts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualenv).